# Jquery css opacity - bug in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, opacity

this

```
$("ul.main_navigation li:not(.active)").children("ul").css({opacity:0}).addClass("hover");
```

hides some uls in navigation. It works fine in all browsers (including ie 6 and ie 7), but in ie8 it hides the uls, but not it's content.

The structure:

```
<ul>
<li><a...></a></li>
<ul>
```

The `<a>` tags are always visible in ie8...

any ideas? thx